# Liquor, alcohol or intoxicant

Tags: word-usage

There are three words Liquor, Alcohol and Intoxicant. Which word can be used in general for any alcoholic drink? That is, if I say, 'wine' does it present any drink or is it a particular drink?

Answer (score 7):

**Liquor** usually refers to "hard" alcohol, that which has been distilled.

**Wine** is a particular drink, usually made from fermented grapes.

**Alcohol** and **intoxicant** are general words, and although people do say "let's have some alcohol" or "let's get intoxicated" it is more usual to say

> Let's go for a **drink**.

with the alcohol being understood.

There are also many synonyms and slang terms such as **booze**, **snifter** which can easily be found with a thesaurus.

Comment: Intoxicant is more general than alcohol, there are other chemicals which will intoxicate you.

Comment: @PeteKirkham yes, and alcohol has other used besides being an intoxicant.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think Pete's point is that, just like all liquor is alcohol, all alcohol is an intoxicant. So it's a further generalization.

Comment: @BrianR I understood that, which is why I said "yes". My point was that not all alcohol is used as an intoxicant, except I mis-spelled "uses".